# Extract specific values from array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to calculate means and averages in a data set, but for many reasons that I can't go into here, my array contains my values and some "filler" values (which are currently set to -1000).

How can I calculate the mean (for example) on **only** the non -1000 values?

```
res=[-1000 for x in range(0,10)]
res[1]=2
res[5]=3
res[7]=4
#something like this?
np.mean(res>-1000)

#the result should be the mean value of 2,3 and 4 (3)
```

MVCE

```
res=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000, -1000]
#for instance
print(np.mean(res[res > -1000]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged `numpy`, you should use it for indexing / slicing. Here's an example:

```
res = np.array([-1000 for x in range(0,10)])
res[1]=2
res[5]=3
res[7]=4

output = np.mean(res[res > -1000])  # 3.0
```

Read the `numpy` [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/user/basics.indexing.html) for more details on indexing logic.

Comment: as is I get this error "TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()" but I'll read up on the doc

Comment: @JessicaChambers, I'm not sure. Did you copy / paste the above code *exactly*? You might also want to supply a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: when I copy it exactly it works, as soon as I put it in my code it throws that error... does the list being full of floats (not ints) make a difference? Otherwise there should be no difference... I will add a MCVE to the original post, just to be sure

Comment: @JessicaChambers, No, `int` vs `float` makes no difference.

Comment: @JessicaChambers, In your example, you need to convert your object to an array first: `res = np.array(res)`

Answer (score 2):

Why use another library when you have your friend `filter` method

```
import statistics
number_list = [2, -1000, 3, 4, -1000, -1000]
not_1000 = list(filter(lambda x: x != -1000, number_list))
not_1000_mean = statistics.mean(not_1000)
```